# Querydict a string

Tags: python, django

I have the following string:

```
string = 'amount=2000|captureDay=0|captureMode=AUTHOR_CAPTURE|currencyCode=978|merchantId=002020000000001|orderId=|transactionDateTime=2012-04-12T12:09:56+02:00|transactionReference=1212943|keyVersion=1|authorisationId=0020000006791167|complementaryCode=|maskedPan=|paymentMeanBrand=IDEAL|paymentMeanType=CREDIT_TRANSFER|responseCode=00'
```

How can i make a querydict out of this.

I want to be able to use `item['amount']` which returns `2000`

EDIT:

what i've tried so far:

```
dict = string.split('|')
```

Output is:

```
['amount=2000', 'captureDay=0', 'captureMode=AUTHOR_CAPTURE', 'currencyCode=978', 'merchantId=002020000000001', 'orderId=', 'transactionDateTime=2012-04-12T12:09:56+02:00', 'transactionReference=1212943', 'keyVersion=1', 'authorisationId=0020000006791167', 'complementaryCode=', 'maskedPan=', 'paymentMeanBrand=IDEAL', 'paymentMeanType=CREDIT_TRANSFER', 'responseCode=00']
```

Comment: Should it return integer `2000`? How do you decide whether int/float/string should be returned?

Comment: The OP has asked to create a `QueryDict` not a `dict`, the behaviour is defined.

Comment: OP - for what reason do you want a Django QueryDict rather than a native dict?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could substitute `|` with `&` and give the whole string to Django's QueryDict.

See the [QueryDict documenation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#querydict-objects)

E.g.

```
In [1]: from django.http import QueryDict

In [2]: sample = 'amount=2000|captureDay=0|captureMode=AUTHOR_CAPTURE|currencyCode=978|merchantId=002020000000001|orderId=|transactionDateTime=2012-04-12T12:09:56+02:00|transactionReference=1212943|keyVersion=1|authorisationId=0020000006791167|complementaryCode=|maskedPan=|paymentMeanBrand=IDEAL|paymentMeanType=CREDIT_TRANSFER|responseCode=00'

In [3]: qdict = QueryDict(sample.replace('|','&'))

In [4]: qdict
Out[4]: <QueryDict: {u'orderId': [u''], u'keyVersion': [u'1'], u'transactionReference': [u'1212943'], u'paymentMeanType': [u'CREDIT_TRANSFER'], u'maskedPan': [u''], u'currencyCode': [u'978'], u'paymentMeanBrand': [u'IDEAL'], u'complementaryCode': [u''], u'amount': [u'2000'], u'authorisationId': [u'0020000006791167'], u'responseCode': [u'00'], u'captureMode': [u'AUTHOR_CAPTURE'], u'captureDay': [u'0'], u'transactionDateTime': [u'2012-04-12T12:09:56 02:00'], u'merchantId': [u'002020000000001']}>
```

Comment: NB: This doesn't work if some of your string values contain `&` symbols in the first place.

Answer (score 3):

```
string = 'amount=2000|captureDay=0|captureMode=AUTHOR_CAPTURE|currencyCode=978|merchantId=002020000000001|orderId=|transactionDateTime=2012-04-12T12:09:56+02:00|transactionReference=1212943|keyVersion=1|authorisationId=0020000006791167|complementaryCode=|maskedPan=|paymentMeanBrand=IDEAL|paymentMeanType=CREDIT_TRANSFER|responseCode=00'
items = dict(item.split('=', 1) for item in string.split('|'))

print items['amount']
```

The first split (on the pipe symbol) yields a list of strings in "x=y" format.  The second split takes each of these and returns a list of two elements.  This list of 2-element lists is then fed into the `dict()` constructor.

Comment: I would use `.split('=', 1)` to make `'a=b=c'` into `{'a': 'b=c'}` instead of raising an exception.

Comment: The OP asked for a `QueryDict`, among other things this allows multiple values per key.

Comment: @yak - I'll amend the answer to include that.

Answer (score 1):

Go for:

```
>>> {i.split("=")[0]:i.split("=")[1] for i in string.split('|')}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dict(e.split("=", 1) for e in string.split("|"))
```